# How to read HtmlDocument in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, dom

i have an aspx page,there is textbox to write an url and a button to show some pictures that are in that url.I can load the url's source code to HtmlDocument.but i dont know how to load pictures from that html source code to show that pictures in my page.How can i do that ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the question more clear so that one can give you a specific answer.

HTML is a markup language which means that there are only format tags, there are no pictures embedded in a .html document. There are only links to images that are urls that can be accessed trough some address. In order to get the images you need to get that url.

If your question is how you can get the actual html from a link then refer to the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575085/how-to-acess-a-website-using-own-asp-net-page/8575181#8575181). But, since you say that you can get the html, then you need to parse it using Regex or HTML Agility Pack.

Code to get the image:

```
byte[] imageData = DownloadData(Url); //DownloadData function from here
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
stream.Close();
```

for method `DownloadData` you can use `WebClient` or `WebRequest` to get the image in a byte array:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("[URL here]");
WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
byte[] b;
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    b = br.ReadBytes(size);
    br.Close();
}

return b;
```